# RxJS - Resolve multiple server calls

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using RxJS in Angular 4 for composing async calls.

I need to call the server, get the response and use it to make another call, get the response for this and use it to make another call and so on. I am using the below code for this and this works as expected

```
id;
name;
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .flatMap(
      (params: Params) => {
        this.id = params['id'];
        return this.myService.get('http://someurlhere');
      }
      )
      .flatMap(
      (response: Response) => {
        return this.myService.get('http://someurlhere');
      })
      .flatMap(
      (response: Response) => {
        return this.myService.get('http://someurlhere');
      })
      .subscribe(
      (response: Response) => {
        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, this.name );
      },
      (error) => {        
        console.log('Error ' + error)
      }
      )
  }
```

Now, I need to make some change to it. In the first flatMap, I need to make 2 rest calls and only proceed when both of them are resolved. Not only this only the response of one of them will be passed onto the next flatMap, as the other call will just populate a variable

```
id;
name;
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .flatMap(
      (params: Params) => {
        this.id = params['id'];
         // this is the 2nd REST call. It just populates a variable, so don't need the output to be passed to next flatMap. However, both the URLs in this section should resolve before the next flatMap is executed.
        this.name = this.myService.get('http://someotherurlhere');
        return this.myService.get('http://someurlhere');
      }
      )
      .flatMap(
      (response: Response) => {
        return this.myService.get('http://someurlhere');
      })
      .flatMap(
      (response: Response) => {
        return this.myService.get('http://someurlhere');
      })
      .subscribe(
      (response: Response) => {
        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, this.name );
      },
      (error) => {        
        console.log('Error ' + error)
      }
      )
  }
```

So, my question is that how should this piece of code be written so that it gets the response back from server, but waits for the other rest call to also complete before moving to the next flatmap.

```
this.name = this.repoService.getDocProperties(this.objectId);
```

Comment: You can use forkJoin to wait until multiple requests are completed https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine async calls with forkJoin

In your case you have two calls:

```
this.myService.get('http://someotherurlhere');
this.myService.get('http://someurlhere');
```

They can be combined like so:

```
let call1 = this.myService.get('http://someotherurlhere');
let call2 = this.myService.get('http://someurlhere');
return Observable.forkJoin([call1, call2])
```

When you subscribe (or chain some other function) to the joined observable the returned data will be in an array. So results from `call1` will be at index 0 and `call2` at index 1.

```
Observable.forkJoin([call1, call2]).subscribe((results) => {
  results[0]; // call1
  results[1]; // call2
});
```

Comment: Thank you. So, what will be the output that will be passed to next flatMap. I just need to pass the output of call2 (and not call1) to the next flatMap

Comment: @kayasa I edited the answer let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: If I do a Observable.forkJoin, then the next flatMap after this throws an error - 'Property 'flatMap' does not exist on type 'Subscription'.'

Comment: @kayasa Are you including the subscription? You shouldn't if your chaining. ex: Observable.forkJoin(...).flatMap(...)...